# Create Arrays for multiple Languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, select, multilingual

I am searching for an easy way to create a select with multiple languages. Currently, I have used a `HELPER` to store an array with my `SELECT` options.

**Helper**

```
list = ["Book", "DVD", "Table", "Chair"]
CATEGORY = Hash[*list.collect { |v| [v, list.index(v)] }.flatten]
```

**View**

```
<%= f.select :category, options_for_select(ApplicationHelper::CATEGORY, selected: 0), { :class => "selectpicker" } %>
```

If there is a way to somehow use the `LOCALE` file this would be amazing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to keep translations in the DB, You can search there are multiple gems available like language select

If you want to pull options from your translation YML files, I suggest options_for_select. All in all something like:

en.yml

```
 en:
   my_options:
     0: "Book"
     1: "DVD"
     2: "Table"
     3: "Chair"
```

View:

```
  <%= f.select :category, options_for_select(t("my_options").invert, selected: 0), { :class => "selectpicker" } %>
```

Rails i18n gives you a hash if you translate a non-leaf key, like "my_options". You need the invert because options_for_select expects the text before the value, and a translation hash is the other way around.

You can explore more about it there are many way to do it this one is one of them and simple way.